# Can one BU decrypt QS parameters from another environment/ BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm preparing for a large redevelopment effort which includes redesigning data structures/data extensions and contacts keys in Salesforce CRM and Marketing Cloud.  To that extent, the Business has decided to go with a completely fresh instance of CRM and migrate contacts from the existing CRM platform to the new one.  In the process, contact keys will be modified, and data structures will be changed.

This causes a ripple effect on other systems, including Marketing Cloud.  To simplify things, they have also decided to build a new MC instance from the ground up, importing Email templates, journeys, etc.

However, where I am currently stuck is trying to identify how I can keep previous email links "alive" without carrying the costs of 2 platforms.  Given that MC encrypts all email links via the `qs` parameter, is there any way I can migrate data from the original MC instance to the new MC instance and continue to make those QS parameters functional?

I suspect that the QS is an encrypted string; is there a way I can simply transfer the encryption keys from the original MC instance?

Alternatively, is there some other approach that I can take which would allow me to maintain email links after decommissioning the environment?  Is there a way I can configure MC to send non-encrypted QS, knowing that I would take responsibility for ensuring confidentiality in parameters?

Comment: I can't help you, but do want to welcome you to the SF side of SE!

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty good question, technically.
I have no technical solution, but that's a typical system switch problem, and I wonder if a technical deep dive into the QS parameter is necessary?

At the core, you want to switch sending systems, and that is common. It's just mostly not two marketing clouds, but that actually makes it easier because of the controls we have -

Normally I would cover it like this: No matter what you do, links aren't valid forever. This is covered by URL expiration in setup. After the expiration period, the links won't work in the "old" system to begin with. Again - this will happen at some point no matter what you do.

So: phase out the old system through purposefully setting URL expiration in setup to something like a month - Depends on your business, but in many lines of business, nobody looks at /clicks a four weeks old newsletter, so this wouldn't be a huge detrimental effect.  And they'd likely have a newer one in the inbox if they wanted to unsubscribe.

Set URL expiration to e.g. four weeks, and once you've stopped sending your last email from the old system, you only need the old system to be up for another month. Without going deep into, as you suggest, copying the encryption params somehow (which I have never seen done), I cannot think of a way with zero overlap. Old emails are out there and for *some days* (if we are generous for a typical b2c newsletter, maybe a week), they sure will be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] where I am currently stuck is trying to identify how I can keep previous email links "alive" without carrying the costs of 2 platforms

I wouldn't bother.

> Alternatively, is there some other approach that I can take which would allow me to maintain email links after decommissioning the environment?

Clicks will still get tracked as long as they aren't expired (as @Jonas Lamberty mentioned).

> Is there a way I can configure MC to send non-encrypted QS, knowing that I would take responsibility for ensuring confidentiality in parameters?

Out of the box, no, but you can append anything you want through [Parameter Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_parameter_management.htm&type=5).  SF monitors unencrypted identifiers and will crack down on it if you try to pass around subscriber key and subscriber id values, etc., in clear text.

The QS parameter is the encrypted [system footprint](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings) *and* context of a specific send to a specific subscriber (e.g. the column values in a the DE and the profile attributes).  If any of those change, the QS value is useless.

I believe the encryption keys are the same across instances, and you may be able to extract some of them on a new CloudPage, but the real issue is that the view-as-a-webpage links/pages are broken as soon as the original sending audience row is gone.  For most campaign automations I've seen, that's the next day.